# getbitmap form TextureView with X and Y offset

Tags: android, bitmap, textureview

`TextureView.getBitmap` can only be used with width and height parameters, does anyone know if it is possible to get a `Bitmap` that is taken from the `TextureView` with a certain X and Y offset?

Comment: Have you tried to get Bitmap from view with `getDrawingCache()`

Comment: Yes I tried, but for some reason the bitmap the resulting Bitmap seems to be empty. I tried setDrawingCacheEnabled and buildDrawingCache on the TextureView, but no result. I also wonder if the performance would improve, as the CreateBitmap is still done on the full scale Bitmap.

Comment: Finaly I found the android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager, which has a very good performance. It is not only fast, but it also returns buffers, so one can use buffer.position(x1).limit(x2) to get only the requested part of a bitmap. There are many good examples using MediaProjectionManager.